# How to reduce object file size when compiling for VxWorks 5.5.1?

Tags: c++, linker, vxworks

I am having trouble with very large object files being produced. We are working with VxWorks 5.5.1, but we have a GCC 4.1.2 available.

Our modules are roughly 6.2MB in size, and we are looking for ways to reduce that. The problem seems to be mainly caused by excessive use of templates. When dumping the symbols in the file using `nm` I get a text-file of 1.8MB. This tells me that almost ⅓ of the file is just the names. Is there any way to reduce the file size?

The following approaches have not worked:

- `--strip-all` seems to have no effect - the output is the same as using `--strip-debug`
- I cannot use `--gc-sections`, because it is not supported for that platform (the option is simply ignored)

I understand that VxWorks links the code at load time, but all it has to link is the C++ runtime library, and I don't want any symbols to be added to the global symbol table, so there should be a way to strip that information, right?

For reference, here is my linker version:

```
i386-wrs-vxworks-ld.exe --version
>>> GNU ld (Wind River VxWorks G++ DWARF-EH 4.1-131) 2.17.50.20070509 
>>> SPR fixes: cq103489 cq111170 cq116027 cq116652 cq118878 cq125145
```

and my compiler version:

```
i386-wrs-vxworks-g++.exe --version
>>> i386-wrs-vxworks-g++.exe (GCC) 4.1.2
```

Comment: Use the `-Os` optimization flag?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that we have already done this, it reduced the output size from 8.5MB to 6.2MB.

Answer (score 4):

I see what you mean by wanting to strip the symbols out of the object. But if you were to strip all the symbols, you wouldn't have any symbol to use as the entry point to start your application. But I believe you still have options. Unfortunately VxWorks 5 is known for having a not very effecient C++ compiler.

If you compiled your application into a *.a (archive - aka static library), you would be able to link this into your operating system at build time, and call this from within usrAppInit.c. This should allow for striping out symbols - or at least moving them to an optional downloaded symbol table. From your application build properties, select the Macros tab and add your archive to the LIBS macro.

To make an archive, goto the build properties and select the Rules tab, then select archive from the dropdown box.

To trim the size of your OS (with your application linked in), modify your vxworks settings. Disable as many components as you can. Also be sure to use a downloaded symbol table (development tool components -> symbol table components -> symbol table initialization componts -> selecte symbol table initialization -> downloaded symbol table). 
This will strip all the symbols out of the OS, and make a downloadable symbol table, that can be downloaded after boot time to debug.

Good luck!

PS. Make sure you have turned off debug (-g) in your compiler. Maybe we could help more if you post your compiler switches.

Answer (score 0):

The way we have normally handled this is to compress the image. You will also need to build the bootrom so that it will decompress to RAM before running. I believe that there are standard makefile options that will allow you to do this.